# How to debug unexpected MSTest interactions in VS 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019, mstest

I have a small but very complex system with somewhere over 2000 tests across 45 test classes.  We recently made some organizational changes to the code being tested.  No code was changed, just where the code resides in the project.  I suspect the reorg only caused a change to the order in which tests run.  You will see why as symptoms are described.

Afterwards, running all tests in the solution resulted in 3 tests in one class failing.  When any of these tests are run explicitly they always pass.  In fact, even running all the tests in the class always results in all tests passing.  I've also tried running running various groups of test classes.  Most groups always result in all tests passing.  Perhaps not unfortunately, I discovered when some large groups of classes are run, completely different tests in other classes consistently fail for similar reasons.

In all cases the failure is related to which version of specific method gets called.  Most tests call mocked versions of other operations.  We don't use a mocking framework or any injection.  The mocked methods are private methods of the test class itself and passed as parameters to constructors or other methods expecting delegates.

Somehow, a test in another test class is doing something that results in the production version of a method being called rather than the mocked version, causing failure. I can't find a quick easy way to tell in what order the tests are running or a quick and easy way to control the order as a means of narrowing down what could be doing it.

My environment is Windows 10 enterprise with VS 2019 16.6.2 testing C# code targeting Core 2.1.

Please understand that I'm looking for suggestions that won't take hours to try.  More than one person has already spent several hours and the problem clearly isn't with the production code so it's hard to justify more time at all but I really don't want to 'just live with it'.

Comment: I'd say, that your tests are not completly isolated. I suppose, that these 3 tests should communicate with the real objects. But some test, that was run before injected a mock and did not clean up this injection. I think you should check, if singletones and all static objects, that will be mocked in your tests, will be cleanp up correctly.

Comment: I'm no longer on that contract due to pandemic related cutbacks however, as I recall, I never solved the problem.  Having said that, "No injection is used anywhere in the project.  All mocked objects are created as private methods within the test class and passed into the class being tested via constructor or method parameters."

Although I won't be able to assess any proposed solution, someone else might benefit from whatever additional comments or solutions anyone sees fit to mention.